# Search in Gmail using imaplib

Tags: python, gmail, imap

```
import imaplib

user = raw_input("Enter your GMail username:")
pwd = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")


m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login(user,pwd)
m.select("[Gmail]/Inbox") # here you a can choose a mail box like INBOX instead
m.search("NEW")
```

I'm trying to select only new messages in Gmail, via imap in Python. Problem is, I always get the following error:

> imaplib.error: command SEARCH illegal
>   in state AUTH

I googled it and read that I'd have to use imap4, but I'm already using it I can't really figure out how to solve it.

Comment: The folder is called `INBOX`, not `[Gmail]/Inbox`.  And I believe that Gmail doesn't support the `\Recent` flag, so searching `NEW` will never match any messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that there is no mailbox called `[Gmail]/Inbox`. It is possible to get a listing of all valid mailboxes by calling `m.list()`.

I discovered this by using Python's interactive shell (with Python 2.6), where it shows the response from the IMAP server for each IMAP operation.

Note: When using the Python interactive shell, importing `pprint` and calling `pprint.pprint(m.<method of m>(<params>))` would probably be a good idea for some IMAP commands which send back lots of information.

Comment: You're right, changing it to "Inbox" solved the problem. Weird though, as the error message was pointing at SEARCH.

Comment: @JacobK: Maybe imaplib only throws exceptions on `BAD`, not on `NO`?  You get a `NO` when trying to `SELECT` a nonexistent folder, but a `BAD` when you try to `SEARCH` without having successfully selected a folder.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing - imaplib's select() function selects INBOX for you by default, seems cleaner.

http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.select

Answer (score 1):

```
import imaplib     
obj = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)    
obj.login('username', 'password')    
obj.select('**label name**') <-- the label in which u want to search message    
obj.search(None, 'FROM', '"LDJ"')
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was having "[Gmail]" that was problematic:

I.e. change this:

```
m.select("[Gmail]/Inbox")
```

to this:

```
m.select("Inbox")
```

Regardless, using m.list() as the person above suggested is a good start.